# Create iid normal random vectors

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, matlab, cholesky-decomposition

**Le us create N independent and identitcally distributed (iid) normal random vectors with zero mean and specific covariance matrix. Each vector is of size p.
Let $\Sigma$ be the specific covariance matrix.**

```
    p = 20;
    N = 50;
    M = chol($\Sigma$)
    Matr =  M' * randn(p, N)
```

In fact I want to know why in all references, they use `chol`?. Why they don't simply write `Matr = randn(N, p) * ($\Sigma$)` ? So what is the advantage of `chol` (or `cholcov`) in this case?

I made some results, and I noticed that they significantly differ when I remove the `chol` !! Even it takes more time for the computation..why??

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution

Comment: And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties property 3